# Disabling all other days in calendar view

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, jtapplecalendar, sfcalendar

I have a form in which the user will select days and then select a date from calendar view..

for example: the user will first select sun and mon .. then click on date button an so calendar view will be shown ..

I want the user just be able to select dates in days sun or mon .. i want to disable the other days and highlight them for example ..

what is the best way to do that?

i saw these two libraries:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

but didn't find anything that helps me do what i need using them..

what is the best way to do that?

Comment: `FSCalendar` allows you to disable `date` selection.

Comment: @Kuldeep yeah its before the calendar view .. first the user will select days and then display calendar with these selected days only in which user can select from them .. the other will be highlighted and disabled

Comment: @Kuldeep yes i know that .. but this is really hard to disable all dates in other days

Comment: what you use objective C or swift?

Comment: @Kuldeep swift 4

Comment: I have done it with swift.

Comment: @Kuldeep how? can you show me example code please?

Comment: I have added code, try this.

Comment: @Kuldeep i will try it and let you know, thanks

Comment: let me know this code helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider Sunday as 1, Monday as 2, Tuesday as 3 and so on Saturday 7.

**Define below globally**

```
fileprivate let gregorian: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    var arrDates = NSMutableArray()
```

Write below line in `viewDidLoad`.

```
arrDates = self.getUserSelectedDates([1, 2], calender: self.calendarVW)
```

**Here 1, 2 means user selected Monday and Tuesday (so This array contains only those dates which are Sunday and Monday)**

**Below is Function that returns Dates array Based on Day value like 1,2 and so on till 7.**

```
func getUserSelectedDates(_ arrWeekDay: [Int], calender calenderVW: FSCalendar?) -> NSMutableArray {
        let arrUnAvailibilityDates = NSMutableArray()
        let currentDate: Date? = calenderVW?.currentPage
        //get calender
        let gregorianCalendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
        // Start out by getting just the year, month and day components of the current date.
        var components: DateComponents? = nil
        if let aDate = currentDate {
            components = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: aDate)
        }
        // Change the Day component to 1 (for the first day of the month), and zero out the time components.
        components?.day = 1
        components?.hour = 0
        components?.minute = 0
        components?.second = 0
        //get first day of current month
        var firstDateOfCurMonth: Date? = nil
        if let aComponents = components {
            firstDateOfCurMonth = gregorianCalendar.date(from: aComponents)
        }
        //create new component to get weekday of first date
        var newcomponents: DateComponents? = nil
        if let aMonth = firstDateOfCurMonth {
            newcomponents = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: aMonth)
        }
        let firstDateWeekDay: Int? = newcomponents?.weekday
        //get last month date
        let curMonth: Int? = newcomponents?.month
        newcomponents?.month = (curMonth ?? 0) + 1
        var templastDateOfCurMonth: Date? = nil
        if let aNewcomponents = newcomponents {
            templastDateOfCurMonth = gregorianCalendar.date(from: aNewcomponents)?.addingTimeInterval(-1)
        }
        // One second before the start of next month
        var lastcomponents: DateComponents? = nil
        if let aMonth = templastDateOfCurMonth {
            lastcomponents = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: aMonth)
        }
        lastcomponents?.hour = 0
        lastcomponents?.minute = 0
        lastcomponents?.second = 0
        var lastDateOfCurMonth: Date? = nil
        if let aLastcomponents = lastcomponents {
            lastDateOfCurMonth = gregorianCalendar.date(from: aLastcomponents)
        }
        var dayDifference = DateComponents()
        dayDifference.calendar = gregorianCalendar

        if arrWeekDay.count == 0 {

        } else if arrWeekDay.count == 1 {
            let wantedWeekDay = Int(arrWeekDay[0])
            var firstWeekDateOfCurMonth: Date? = nil
            if wantedWeekDay == firstDateWeekDay {
                firstWeekDateOfCurMonth = firstDateOfCurMonth
            } else {
                var day: Int = wantedWeekDay - firstDateWeekDay!
                if day < 0 {
                    day += 7
                }
                day += 1
                components?.day = day
                firstWeekDateOfCurMonth = gregorianCalendar.date(from: components!)
            }
            var weekOffset: Int = 0
            var nextDate: Date? = firstWeekDateOfCurMonth
            repeat {
                let strDT: String = getSmallFormatedDate(convertCalendarDate(toNormalDate: nextDate))!
                arrUnAvailibilityDates.add(strDT)
                weekOffset += 1
                dayDifference.weekOfYear = weekOffset
                var date: Date? = nil
                if let aMonth = firstWeekDateOfCurMonth {
                    date = gregorianCalendar.date(byAdding: dayDifference, to: aMonth)
                }
                nextDate = date
            } while nextDate?.compare(lastDateOfCurMonth!) == .orderedAscending || nextDate?.compare(lastDateOfCurMonth!) == .orderedSame
        }
        else {
            for i in 0..<arrWeekDay.count {
                let wantedWeekDay = Int(arrWeekDay[i])
                var firstWeekDateOfCurMonth: Date? = nil
                if wantedWeekDay == firstDateWeekDay {
                    firstWeekDateOfCurMonth = firstDateOfCurMonth
                } else {
                    var day: Int = wantedWeekDay - firstDateWeekDay!
                    if day < 0 {
                        day += 7
                    }
                    day += 1
                    components?.day = day
                    firstWeekDateOfCurMonth = gregorianCalendar.date(from: components!)
                }


                var weekOffset: Int = 0
                var nextDate: Date? = firstWeekDateOfCurMonth
                repeat {
                    let strDT = getSmallFormatedDate(convertCalendarDate(toNormalDate: nextDate))
                    arrUnAvailibilityDates.add(strDT!)
                    weekOffset += 1
                    dayDifference.weekOfYear = weekOffset
                    var date: Date? = nil
                    if let aMonth = firstWeekDateOfCurMonth {
                        date = gregorianCalendar.date(byAdding: dayDifference, to: aMonth)
                    }
                    nextDate = date
                } while nextDate?.compare(lastDateOfCurMonth!) == .orderedAscending || nextDate?.compare(lastDateOfCurMonth!) == .orderedSame
            }
        }
        return arrUnAvailibilityDates
    }


func getSmallFormatedDate(_ localDate: Date?) -> String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
        if let aZone = timeZone {
            dateFormatter.timeZone = aZone as TimeZone
        }
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        var dateString: String? = nil
        if let aDate = localDate {
            dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: aDate)
        }
        return dateString
    }

    func convertCalendarDate(toNormalDate selectedDate: Date?) -> Date? {
        let sourceTimeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let destinationTimeZone = NSTimeZone.system as NSTimeZone
        var sourceGMTOffset: Int? = nil
        if let aDate = selectedDate {
            sourceGMTOffset = sourceTimeZone?.secondsFromGMT(for: aDate)
        }
        var destinationGMTOffset: Int? = nil
        if let aDate = selectedDate {
            destinationGMTOffset = destinationTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: aDate)
        }
        let interval1 = TimeInterval((destinationGMTOffset ?? 0) - (sourceGMTOffset ?? 0))
        var localDate: Date? = nil
        if let aDate = selectedDate {
            localDate = Date(timeInterval: interval1, since: aDate)
        }
        return localDate
    }
```

**Below is FSCalendar delegates**

```
extension ViewController: FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    }

    func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
        arrDates = self.getUserSelectedDates([3, 4], calender: self.calendarVW)
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
        if arrDates.contains(dateFormatter2.string(from: date)) {
            return UIColor.green
        } else {
            return UIColor.red
        }
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        if arrDates.contains(dateFormatter2.string(from: date)) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: calendar didn't change means?

Comment: yeah all days are shown .. am i supposed to change something in the code?

Comment: as you asked in your question that you want to allow only Sun and Mon dates and you want to disable other dates with colors, so this code execute same as you want.

Comment: @mrs.tat, I have create demo and tested well, and it works perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170145/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-mrs-tat).

Comment: @mrs.tat, I think you missing something.

Comment: my bad x_x i forgot to set delegate and datasource of the calendar .. WORKS PERFECTLY!

Comment: can you help me further with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307950/disabling-past-days-in-fscalendar

Comment: can you please?

Comment: @mrs.tat, what's the problem you facing?

Comment: am getting a wrong current date + i want to disable past days

Comment: @mrs.tat, I post answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307950/disabling-past-days-in-fscalendar question

Comment: how can i do same thing in https://github.com/Vodolazkyi/VACalendar @Kuldeep

Answer (score 2):

for JTApplecalendar this is easy

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, shouldSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) -> Bool {
    return cellState.day == .monday || cellState.day == .sunday
}
```

Done.

Comment: You are awesome brother. Really.

Comment: Hi I need one more help, how can autoselect the current date as default and I need to avoid selection for previous date?

Comment: auto selecting the current date when your app loads is also easy. Inside your viewDidLoad function, just do ---> `calendarView.selectDate( Date() )`

Answer (score 1):

For function calendar check Saturday or Sunday then it did not select.
The solution for Swift 4.2:

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
   return CheckSatSunday(today: date)
}

// Check Today Is Saturday or Sunday

func CheckSatSunday(today:Date) ->Bool{

 var DayExist:Bool
   // let today = NSDate()

    let calendar = 
     NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let components = calendar!.components([.weekday], from: today)

    if components.weekday == 1 {
        print("Hello Sunday")
        self.showToast(message: "Sunday is Off")
        DayExist = false
    } else if components.weekday == 7{
        print("Hello Saturday")
        self.showToast(message: "Saturday is Off")
         DayExist = false
    } else{
        print("It's not Saturday and  Sunday ")
        DayExist = true
    }
    print("weekday :\(String(describing: components.weekday)) ")
    return DayExist
}
```